# DevTools Console - Turn it off

Tags: javascript, logging, google-chrome-devtools

I'm currently building a library in Javascript and really like Google's DevTools for debugging it. Unfortunately I don't want my library to log when I release.

This is how my logger is currently setup.

```
var debug = false;

var increaseSomething = function()
{
    // Random Code...

    if (debug) { console.log("Increased!"); }
}
```

Unfortunately this is quite annoying, I shouldn't have to check if debug is on before logging to the console every call.

I could try to encapsulate the console in my own logging object but I feel that wouldn't be such a great idea. Any thoughts?

Comment: I'll post it again, did you look at [this](http://benalman.com/projects/javascript-debug-console-log/) ?

Comment: @adeneo I did not, looked promising since its cross-browser compatible but doesn't include some of chromes console functionality. If I must I could probably extend that.

Comment: It's a bit confusing at first, using debug and not console, but it is convenient, and has an easy way to disable all logging -> `debug.setLevel(0)` and lots of other neat features. Just overwriting the log() function does'nt sound like a great idea to me !

Comment: @adeneo Yes I agree. Overriding it would cause others more pain than its worth. I've encapsulated a log function into another function to see if debug was on. I guess I'll do it this way for now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I thought about encapsulating the console logger again and instead of coming up with an entire object to encapsulate the console I created a function that takes in a console method. Then it checks if debugging is on and calls the function.

```
var debug = true;

var log = function (logFunction) {
    if (debug) {
        logFunction.apply(console, Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments, 1));
    }
};

var check = function (canvas) {
    log(console.groupCollapsed, "Initializing WebGL for Canvas: %O", canvas);
    log(console.log, "cool");

    log(console.groupEnd);
};

check(document.getElementById('thing'));
```

I do like @Aesthete's ideas but I'm not yet wanting to make the encapsulated console.
Here is the jsfiddle as example: http://jsfiddle.net/WRe29/

Here I add a `debugCall` to the Objects prototype. Same as the log function just a different name so theirs no 'overlap' Now any object can call `debugCall` and check its `debug` flag.

```
Object.prototype.debugCall = function(logFunction)
{
    if (this.debug) { logFunction.apply(console, Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments, 1)); } 
};

var Thing = { debug : true /*, other properties*/ };
Thing.debugCall(console.log, "hello world");
```

**EDIT:**

My initial thoughts were to use an object as the 'configuration' to indicate whether the object should be logging. I've used this a while and liked the configuration concept but didn't think everyone would be so keen to use configuration objects in their code alongside a function being passed to a extended function on object. Thus I took the concept and instead looked at function decoration.

```
Function.prototype.if = function (exp) {
    var exFn = this; 
    return function () {
        if (exp) exFn.apply(this, arguments); 
    };
};

var debug = false;

console.log = console.log.if(debug);
console.group = console.group.if(debug);
// Console functions...
myFunction = myFunction.if(debug);
```

It's very simple almost unnecessary to even have a decoration function that checks an expression but I am not willing to put if statements everywhere in my code. Hope this helps someone out maybe even spark their interest with function decoration.

**Note**: This way will also kill logging for everyone unless you setup the if extension correctly ;) *cough some type of object/library configuration indicating debug

Answer (score 5):

You could do this?

```
if (!debug) {
  console.log = function() {/* No-op */}
}
```

As you mentioned, you might not want to kill all logging for everyone. This is how I usually go about it. Define these in some utility file, as global functions. I usually add additional functions for `LOG`, `WARN`, `ERROR` and `TRACE`, and log these based on a verbosity level.

```
// Define some verbosity levels, and the current setting.
_verbosityLevels = ["TRACE", "LOG", "WARN", "ERROR"];
_verbosityCurrent = _verbosityLevels.indexOf("LOG");

// Helper function.
var checkVerbosity = function(level) { 
  return _verbosityLevels.indexOf(level) <= _verbosityCurrent; 
}

// Internal log function.
var _log = function(msg, level) {
  if(!debug && checkVerbosity(level)) console.log(msg);
}

// Default no-op logging functions.
LOG = function() {/* no-op */}
WARN = function() {/* no-op */}

// Override if console exists.
if (console && console.log) {
  LOG = function(msg) { 
    _log(msg, "LOG");
  }
  WARN = function(msg) {
    _log(msg, "WARN");
  }
}
```

This also allows you to add important information to your log, such as time, and caller locations.

```
console.log(time + ", " + arguments.callee.caller.name + "(), " + msg);
```

This may output something like this:

```
"10:24:10.123, Foo(), An error occurred in the function Foo()"
```

Comment: Then just assign every part of the console methods to empty functions? Neat idea.

Comment: @Nate - Just call `console.log()` like you normally would, but if this line is processed early, logging won't do anything.

Comment: Right except console has more methods than just log. Plus I'm not sure if I want to kill console for everyone else when they use my library...

Comment: @Nate - Sure, that is understandable. I've made an edit and shown how I usually handle it.

Comment: Yea I don't necessarily want to create a wrap around it but its definitely the way to go for more control. Thanks for the help! +1

Answer (score 0):

https://github.com/pimterry/loglevel

Log level Library::Try whether this suits ur need.